# Temperature of rod if end points are different temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, heat, temperature

How does the temperature vary along the length of the rod if its both ends are at different temperature. As an example, consider the problem:

> 20 cm long rod has rod at one end 100 ºC and another end at 0 ºC. Find the temperature at the center of the rod when it's in thermal steady state.

Answer (score 1):

It is a quite basic problem driven by a one-dimensional second order ordinary differential equation with two boundary conditions, the temperature prescribed at the two ends, known as the [`Heat Equation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation). Do not forget to express the temperature in `Kelvin` and remove the time-dependent term since you are only interested in the final steady-state solution.